# Why is my Document Mode: IE7 standards in HTML5 page?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Here is my source code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="ctl00_ctl00_Head1">                
<title>my page</title>   
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />        
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteMain/JS/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know why but I think you can fix this when setting this meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,8,7,5" />`

Comment: @sofl The meta tag is ignored if `X-UA-Compatible` is sent in the HTTP headers or if local browser settings are forcing a particular mode.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're looking at it from a local or intranet server, and you have the setting 'View all intranet pages in compatibility mode' ticked, probably.